# Angular 2 url definition as parameter

Tags: angular

I created a simple Angular 2 application. The first page contains a login. Originally I am simple java developer and I would like to use the base url of the login as a parameter. In a back-end world I store the base url in a database or in a file (key value or xml/json) and if the url is changed I need to change the parameter without development. (and our customers can make the changes without any magic)
I saw that I can define more environments in nodejs and create a build for dev/test ... but I need a new build. Is it possible to define anyhow a config file for the Angular app and use the parameter as a service base url similar in Java the Property object or in Spring the classpath property? For example I will create an admin page where I parse every keys and a business user set the correct values for example replace the localhost to mydomain.com.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Won't your app simply send requests to the server it comes from? In that common case, you don't need any base URL. Just use `/api/foo/bar` instead of `http://example.com/api/foo/bar`.

Comment: Hope this repo helps you https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

Comment: The Angular app and the service provider can be installed on different host.

Comment: @GaborSandor sure. But will they be?

Comment: So in front-end project the dynamic services are not existing? In a simple java world I create a property file that contain the urls and I need to change only the url and I dont need to create a new jar. I would like to create an Ionic based project and later compile as mobile and web app. So the host of the services will be different.